# Comma style button to format numbers with 1,000 separators in Excel not working as required

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I am working with several large Excel spreadsheets with values frequently into the 10s of millions, so quickly comparing numbers by eye can be tricky. To help, I often format cells with 1,000 separators. However, the 'comma style' button in the number group on the home tab of the ribbon (pictured below) automatically formats numbers to 2 decimal places - even if the original number was an integer. These extra decimal places then widen my columns, so I have to click 'decrease decimal' twice, then adjust column widths manually to get the formatting back as I'd like it. This is quite a lot of work!

[Screenshot of Excel's 'comma style' button in the number group of the home tab of the ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooqGs.png)

Is there a way to change the default behaviour of the 'comma style' button so it preserves the number of decimal places that each cell initially had? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.  I deal with that so frequently in my job as a financial systems developer that it's basically just a natural reaction now that I click the decrease/increase decimal buttons after clicking the Comma Style button.

You could write a macro to do it and assign that action to a ribbon button.

Comment: Thank you. It's frustrating, but good to know I'm not the only one with this problem! I'm no expert on macros, but will have a look into it, and post here if I find a solution.

Comment: In newer Excel versions, look for the Cell Styles button (Styles tab) or the Styles gallery (shown if there is space on the ribbon). It should contain a style marked as `Comma [0]`

Comment: @Paul That particular style, while adding the commas, completely hides the decimals.  Desire is to preserver the original number of decimal places.

Comment: @whv20 Paul has a good point.  You -could- create new styles in order to work around this.  You would have to create a different style for each number of decimals you would want to maintain, though.